# How to extend express Request type in a ts-node project?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/340760), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51086613/340760), etc

```
// ./typings/express/index.d.ts
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
     token?: string
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import * as express from 'express'

(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {

  const foo = req.token

}
```

It does work if I compile directly (`tsc -p .`), it does work in Visual Code, but when I try to run with `ts-node` I always get:

> error TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Request'.

Any idea how can I make it work with ts-node?

Versions: `ts-node@7.0.1` `typescript@3.0.1`

Comment: Where did you defines it?

Comment: `./typings/express/index.d.ts`, I also tried with and without `typeRoots`

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround that worked for me was enabling the files flag

```
ts-node --files index.ts
```

and for mocha

```
TS_NODE_FILES=true mocha
```